# Change color/button type AND keep caret on click Bootstrap dropdown menu menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm brand new to JS, but using other Stack posts, I got this far.  Thanks in advance!

This bootstrap drop down button works however the desired result is that the drop down button change colors based on the selection AND the drop down button keep the "drop down caret" each time it is clicked.  In other words it has to remain a dropdown menu button instead of becoming a regular button on click. I have no idea how to set the class and/or change the color for each option chosen.

So selecting power on would result in a green drop down button labeled "Power On".  Or Power Off = red etc...

https://jsfiddle.net/1buok5mn/

```js
    $(function () { <!-- change text in power button -->

        $(".dropdown-menu").on('click', 'li a', function () {
            $(".btn:first-child").text($(this).text());
            $(".btn:first-child").val($(this).text());

        });

    });
```

```html
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Power On/Off <span class="caret"></span>

        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Power On</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Low Power</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Power Off</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **[DEMO page](https://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/1buok5mn/4/)** which works fine..

```
    <div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" id="ddl">
    Power On/Off <span class="caret"></span>
 </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#" id="1" >Power On</a></li>

    <li><a href="#" id="2" >Low Power</a></li>

    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="3" >Power Off</a></li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

This is jquery part

```
 $('ul li a').click(function(e) 
    {   
        var id = $(this).attr('id')
    if(id=="1")
    {
        $('#ddl').removeClass('btn-default');
         $('#ddl').removeClass('alert-warning');
         $('#ddl').removeClass('alert-danger');
        $('#ddl').addClass('alert-success'); 
        $('#ddl').text('Power On');
    }
        if(id=="2")
    {
        $('#ddl').removeClass('btn-default');
        $('#ddl').removeClass('alert-success');
         $('#ddl').removeClass('alert-danger');
        $('#ddl').addClass('alert-warning'); 
        $('#ddl').text('Low Power');
    }
        if(id=="3")
    {
         $('#ddl').removeClass('btn-default');
         $('#ddl').removeClass('alert-success');
         $('#ddl').removeClass('alert-warning');
         $('#ddl').addClass('alert-danger');        
        $('#ddl').text('Power Off');
    }

    });
```

Comment: This works partially.  However, it still needs the text in the button to change to what was selected as it did in the original code.  Also, I'm wondering if there might be a way to change the class with less code than 3 removes and one add for each id.